# Need help to build correct associations between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have two models: `User` and `Channel`. There are 4 types of channels with different prices: animal channel for 1000, a news channel for 800, etc. Each user can subscribe to different channels, so eventually, I've created three models with the following associations:

```
Channel
has_many :user_channels
has_many :users, through: :user_channels

User 
has_many :user_channels
has_many :channels, through: :user_channels

UserChannel
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :channel
```

But I am not sure it's the correct way to handle it.

Also what's confusing is that when I try to get the price of the channel for a particular user  as `user.user_channels.price` where `price` is the field of `Channel` result is the collection actually which seems wrong to me, but again I am only learning.

the schema:

```
create_table "channels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "user_channels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "channel_id"
    t.decimal "spent_amount"
    t.date "start_date"
    t.date "due_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: That's because you are asking it for all the user's channels. If a user has many channels and a channel has many users, you need to specify which channel you are asking the price of. Can you please edit your question and show us your schema so I can see what columns you have defined?

Comment: thanks for the reply! sure give  a moment

Comment: @Beartech i've added the schema too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking the DB the right question. If you want to know the price of a channel, how can JUST knowing the user tell you that? Since `UserChannel` is a relation table, you are asking it "give me all of this user's channels" with `user.user_channels`. Which is a collection.

```
@my_channels = user.user_channels
#=> returns an array of UserChannels objects NOT an array of channels
```

You have to tell it WHICH channel you want the price of. There are many ways to do that:

```
@my_var = user.channels.where(category: 'animals')
```

That will give you an array of whatever meets that criteria. If the category column has a unique constraint it will just give you one result but will still be in an array.

```
@my_var = user.channels.find_by(category: 'animals')
```

will call that query and give the first item that returns as a `#<channel>` object. you can then query the price of:

```
@my_var.price #or all in one:
@my_var = user.channels.find_by(category: 'animals').price
```

You shouldn't need to access `user_channels` directly. And I would normally have named it `users_channels` to denote the two-way nature of the has_many_through, since you can do things like:

```
@channel = Channel.first
@channel.users 
#=> returns an array of all users that have that channel.
```

Comment: I would get into the rails console and play around with associations until you get a feel for them. When you make a query, look at what is returned. Is it a single object, an array of objects, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @beartech ! I totally missed the part when you can access `user.channels` without the connecting table, my bad.

Comment: just one more question if I can? if i want to get `spent_amount ` for user for a certain channel, do I need to use `join` or is there an easier way?

Comment: You don't need a join to get the numbers and sum them. `pluck` is a great method to know. You can do `@some_channel.user.pluck(:spent_amount)` which returns an array of those amounts. That means you can do any `Array` operation like: '@some_channel.user.pluck(:spent_amount).sum` and get a sum total.

Comment: Worth a read: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I really encourage you to read that link. It's super helpful. The methods available are numerous. Since `sum` is a SQL function they made a method for it. Instead of my `.pluck` example you can just do: `@some_channel.users.sum(:spent_amount)` -note I made `user` singular in that pluck example in the previous comment, that is a typo.

Comment: And not to overwhelm you, but since Rails loves `hash_with_indifferent_access` it's worth noting that it can be either: `@some_channel.users.sum(:spent_amount)` or `@some_channel.users.sum("spent_amount")` and Rails with recognize either the string or the symbol as the same.

Comment: will do so, informative indeed! thanks! about hashes I already know as i've had some experience with them but never with pluck, so your response is super helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

> Also what's confusing is that when I try to get the price of the channel for a particular user as user.user_channels.price where price is the field of Channel result is the collection actually which seems wrong to me, but again I am only learning.
>   If you want to know the price on channel for the particular user, you need to do this

`# Assume you know ids of user and channel both.
    user = User.find(1).includes(:channels) #Preload channeles to look through them finding seeking channel and its price
    channel_id = 1
    price = user.channels.find_by(id: channel_id)&.price # User might not be subscribed to the channel. In that scenario the price will be nil.`

Comment: Also, there is not need to actualy look though user_channels as channel price does not depend on user_channels table as it stored in channel itself.